# ObjectInput/OutputStream seems to not serialize/Deserialize

Tags: java, serialization

I'm writing a fairly simple program, which needs to save some simple data between runs. This data is defined by UserData, outlined below:

```
public class UserData implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3542558265070011448L;

public static ArrayList<String> projectList; 

public static ArrayList<Bill> billList;

public static String userName;

public static String userEmail; 

public UserData() {

}

public UserData(String name, String email) {
    super();
    userName = name;
    userEmail = email;
    projectList = new ArrayList<String>();
    billList = new ArrayList<Bill>();

}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public String getUserEmail() {
    return userEmail;
}

public ArrayList<Bill> getBillList() {
    return billList;

}

public ArrayList<String> getProjectList() {
    return projectList;

}

public void setBillList(Bill theBill) {
    billList.add(theBill);
}

public void setProjectList(String projectName) {
    projectList.add(projectName);
}
```

}

I Then have a class which handles serializing/deserializing of this data and it's instance to a file, with the various calls done directly or indirectly by events in a separate Gui Class. This is it:

```
public class FileHandler implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 473118590700911358L;
private static JFileChooser fileChooser;
public UserData myUserData;

public FileHandler() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    initData();
}

public FileHandler(UserData newUser) {
    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    myUserData = newUser;
    System.out.println("Entered User: " + myUserData.getUserName());
    System.out.println("Entered User: " + myUserData.getUserEmail());
}

private void createProgramData() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("data\\ProgramData.diy");
    ObjectOutputStream encoderp = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    System.out.println("createProgramData: " + myUserData.getUserName());
    System.out.println("createProgramData: "+ myUserData.getUserEmail());
    encoderp.writeObject(myUserData);
    encoderp.close();
    fileOut.close();

}

public void exportData() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    final int selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    ObjectOutputStream encodere = null;

    if (selectedFile == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        final File selectedPath = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(selectedPath + "\\UserData.diy");
            encodere = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            System.out.println("Writing Data: " + myUserData.getUserName());
            System.out.println("Writing Data: " + myUserData.getUserEmail());
            encodere.writeObject(myUserData);
            encodere.close();
            fileOut.close();
    }

}

public void importData() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    final int selectedFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    ObjectInputStream decoderim = null;

    if (selectedFile == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            final File selectedPath = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(selectedPath);
            decoderim = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            myUserData = (UserData)decoderim.readObject();
            decoderim.close();
            fileIn.close();
            System.out.println("importing Data: " + myUserData.getUserEmail());
            System.out.println("importing Data: " + myUserData.getUserName());

    }

}

private void initData() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("data\\ProgramData.diy");
    ObjectInputStream decoderi = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    myUserData = (UserData)decoderi.readObject();
    decoderi.close();
    fileIn.close();
    System.out.println("initializing Data: " + myUserData.getUserName());
    System.out.println("Initializing Data: " + myUserData.getUserEmail());

}

public UserData getUserData() {
    return myUserData;
}
```

A problem I'm having with the `ObjectInputStream` and possibly `ObjectOutputStream` seems to be that when I serialize UserData, exit my program, and then re-enter and try to import that file, the instance of UserData remains unchanged. I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing. Even pointing out something I've overlooked helps.

Comment: It doesn't 'come back null'. It might come back with all its fields null, but it can only come back as a null if you serialized a null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserData` only has static fields, and static fields aren't serialized. From the look of your code they should all be instance members. Don't make anything `static` unless you know exactly why you are doing so.